# Google Apps Script - why is it not finding the matching value?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script

I have an if else statement inside of a for loop. My goal is to have it look through existing customers in the WIP sheet. If it finds a match to the one currently selected in the Renderings sheet, it updates the other values for that customer.

Edit: I've edited the code to show more of what I'm trying to accomplish instead of an extremely simplified version and included a sample spreadsheet.

Edit: I FIGURED IT OUT!!! The problem was with my else if statement. It needed to be `i == wipValues.length-1` instead of `i = wipValues.length + 1`

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const rdSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Renderings");
  const wipSheet = ss.getSheetByName("WIP");

  var cell = e.range;
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var col = cell.getColumn();

  //if status is changed in Rendering sheet
  if (activeSheet.getSheetName() == 'Renderings' && col == 12) {
    //Gets Rendering sheet variables - active sheet
    var rdValues = rdSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 16).getValues();
    var rdWO = rdValues[0][0];
    var rdCustomer = rdValues[0][1];
    var rdQTY = rdValues[0][2];
    var rdJobNotes = rdValues[0][3];
    var rdRevNum = rdValues[0][5];
    var rdAppV = rdValues[0][7];
    var rdTime = rdValues[0][8];
    var rdRd = rdValues[0][9];
    var rdSales = rdValues[0][10];
    var rdRdDate = rdValues[0][13];
    var rdProdDate = rdValues[0][14];

    //Gets WIP sheet variables - inactive sheet
    var wipRange = wipSheet.getDataRange();
    var wipValues = wipRange.getValues();

    Logger.log('looking for ' + rdCustomer + ' match in WIP');
    //looks for customer name and job notes match in WIP
    for (let i = 0; i < wipValues.length; i++) {
      if (wipValues[i][1] === rdCustomer && wipValues[i][3] === rdJobNotes) {
        Logger.log('Match found in WIP');
        wipValues[i][0] = rdWO;
        wipValues[i][2] = rdQTY;
        wipRange.setValues(wipValues);
        Logger.log('WO updated in WIP');
        break;

      }
      else if (i = wipValues.length + 1) {
        Logger.log('match not found');
        break;
      }
    }
    return;
  }
  //if status is changed in WIP sheet
  else if (activeSheet.getSheetName() == 'WIP' && col == 22) {
    return;
  }
}
```

For some reason, it's not recognizing when there is a matching customer name. I think the problem is with my if statement and/or how I'm declaring my variables for wipValues and rdCustomer.

Here is a link to a [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gtA4Pt-xNVjQ-F_LwENKqythKeynq3GOw1Yxm8ZwgfU/edit?usp=sharing)

In the sample, it's supposed find "The Most OK Business" or "Mom & Pop" in the WIP sheet if the status is changed in the Renderings sheet.

Comment: What is `e` it is undefined.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention everything from var row and up are actually defined in an onEdit(e) function where I call for the RD_StatusChange(ss, rdSheet, wipSheet, cell, value, row) function. I just included them in this example so you'd have them.

Comment: Your answer doesn't help explain how `e` is defined.  Revise your code to show how.

Comment: "The onEdit(e) trigger runs automatically when a user changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet. Most onEdit(e) triggers use the information in the event object to respond appropriately." -https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#:~:text=%7D-,onEdit(e),event%20object%20to%20respond%20appropriately.

Comment: it triggers the function if I change a cell in the rdSheet

Comment: Yes but the e is not defined in your example

Comment: That's because you don't define e in onEdit(e) functions. e is used to indicate when an e(vent) happens - in this case, when a cell value is changed - run the function automatically.

Comment: From your showing script and your current issue, can I think of your current issue by correctly replicating your current issue? I would like to approach the reason for your current issue by replicating your issue. So, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue? And, when you can provide your expected result, it will help think of a solution. But, if you cannot do it, please don't worry.

Comment: `That's because you don't define e in onEdit(e) functions.` There is no need for sarcasm; everyone understands that `e` "simply" returns the Event Objects for `onEdit`. You say that there is an 'OnEdit` function that includes a call to `RD_StatusChange(ss, rdSheet, wipSheet, cell, value, row)`. What is noticeable is that `e` isn't passed as a parameter. So, we are simply asking how is a line like `var cell = e.range;` evaluated when `e` isn't a parameter in `RD_StatusChange()`?

Comment: I see where the confusion is now. I thought they "simply" didn't know what e was because I didn't know what it was when I started writing this program. This is my first program so I ask that you be gentle with me, Watson. It's funny you read my honest attempt to explain e as sacarm . I now realize I did poorly in trying to simplify my program in order to ask my question. I will edit the e out so there's less confusion. I hope it helps

Comment: I changed my mind and decided to just make it an onEdit function. Hopefully, this makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if (i == wipValues.length - 1)
```

instead of

```
else if (i = wipValues.length + 1)
```